# Two apps for the same Xamarin.Forms project deploy to android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

When I deploy the `Xamarin.Forms` app to my physical device or emulator, if it is from Visual Studio, it shows two apps, one with `.android` extension. When I deploy it from the Microsoft App center, It deploys one apk file and installs two apps. See the below image.
[image]
It happened after I added the app icon and splash activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you added `SplashActivity.cs`, it has `MainLauncher = true`, so now you need to set `MainLauncher = false` in your `MainActivity.cs`

Comment: How to remove the .android extension from the app?

Comment: Try adding a Label in SplashActivity.cs, like this `[Activity(Label = "VaxineApp", MainLauncher = true, ...`

Comment: The splash screen takes a long time; how can I control the time of the splash screen?

Comment: I guess you followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen) when you were implementing your splash screen. If you did, then you should remove the line `await Task.Delay (8000);` from `SplashActivity` or put there a smaller delay. If you didn't folow this tutorial, I'm not sure what might be the problem... I guess you should then create a new question and post the code of your `SplashActivity`

Comment: Yes! I have followed that tutorial, and I have removed the `Task.Delay(8000);`, but it still adds delay.